# Which one is better ? Executing script directly from control machine or copy and execute locally?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

There are following two ways to run a script on the target machine:

```
1.  - name: run the script from the control machine directly.
      script: "{{path_to_scripts}}/script.sh"

2.  - name: Copying the script from target machine.
      copy: src="{{path_to_scripts}}/script.sh" dest="{{path_to_scripts}}/script.sh" mode=0777

    - name: Execute script locally.
      command: /bin/sh {{path_to_scripts}}/script.sh
```

As i am running the playbook against more than 30 target machines. I would like to know which one will be a better choice ?

Also what is the performance penalty if i prefer one over other ?

Comment: note "what is the performance" questions are best answered by running your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are executing the script from the ansible machine, the ansible server will copy the script to temp location in the remote machine to execute.

So, the better choice is "run the script from the control machine directly" because of below reasons

1. you dont need to ssh to all 30 machines for copy the scripts
2. you can have a single line of code to do the same that needs 2
   steps(copy and execute)
3. no performance difference as both methods is doing the same
   operations

Comment: I was running that locally to verify something at target host. But it is only verifying locally, 
for example If I have to verify whether a directory is empty or not in target hot, then it only verifying locally.
For example,
- name: Checking an empty directory
  script: /home/npwa-ansible/utility/xyz/files/empty_dir_bash.sh "/some_target_dir_location"

Answer (score 0):

If the script has to do something on the remote machine, would be better if you copy it and execute directly on the remote. I don't think you would see any noticeable performance decrease in any of the two cases.

The only thing is that in case 1. you will have to ssh to the remote and execute the commands you need, thing that ansible already does for you.